# How could a component pass itself as an argument in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not even sure if this is do-able, but let's say i have this :

```
<p id='1' disabled={this.anyfunction(???)}>Hello wurld</p>
```

and that would be my function

```
anyfuction:function(component){
    console.log(component.id)
}
```

What parameter should i pass to the function ? `this` wont work, i've tried to `bind(this)` but the problem is that the function isnt called ( can't do something like `myfunction().bind(this)` eventhough `myfunction.bind(this)` would work, it's not being called when the HTML renders).

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's your end goal here? [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i'm trying to check if a component name is present in an array of predefined strings ( matching the name ) and if so, i'd disable that component

Comment: Have you tried, `this.anyFunc.bind(this, 'parameter')()`

Answer (score 1):

you can pass parameters from the render like

> `this.anyFunc.bind(this, 'my parameter')`

Comment: That only works when you're passing a handler function. In this case, the OP is using the value to calculate if the `p` is `disabled` via immediate execution.

Comment: the OP asks how to send parameters, solution would be assign to a var result of calling it, i dont see any parameter in your answer

Comment: The OP asks how to send the component itself as a parameter. Using either of the methods I posted, it's unnecessary as you can reference the component via `this`.

Comment: can't do something like myfunction().bind(this) eventhough myfunction.bind(this) would work, it's not being called when the HTML renders

Comment: `this.anyFunc.bind(this, 'parameter')()` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `bind`, you could use `call`:

```
this.anyfunction.call(this, some, other, parameters);
```

But, unless I'm missing something, I think you want something like:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let isDisabled = this.anyFunction();

    return (
      <p id='1' disabled={ isDisabled }>Hello wurld</p>
    );
  }

  anyFunction() {
    // you can reference the component w/ this
    return this.props.somethingPassedIn;
  }
};
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more ? i dont get the this.props.smth into the function

Comment: @JorelAmthor - That was just a placeholder for whatever logic you need to write to get the calculated value.